# Easiest way to convert a string into a HashMap

Tags: parsing, kotlin

if I have some text in a String like:

> "abc=123,def=456,ghi=789"

how could I create a populated `HashMap<String,Int>` object for it in the easiest, shortest amount of code possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I can think of no solution easier than this:

```
val s = "abc=123,def=456,ghi=789"

val map = s.split(",").associate { 
    val (left, right) = it.split("=")
    left to right.toInt() 
}
```

Or, if you need exactly a `HashMap`, use [`.associateTo(HashMap()) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-to.html).

Some details:

- [`.associate { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) receives a function that produces pairs which are then stored into a map as keys and values respectively.
- `val (left, right) = it.split("=")` is the usage of [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) on the list returned from [`it.split("=")`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html), it takes the first two items from the list.
- [`left to right.toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) creates a `Pair<String, Int>` defining a single mapping.

Answer (score 4):

You can map each key/value to a `Pair` with the `to` keyword. An iterable of `Pair` can be mapped to a Map easily with the `toMap()` extension method.

```
val s = "abc=123,def=456,ghi=789"
val output = s.split(",")
              .map { it.split("=") }
              .map { it.first() to it.last().toInt() }
              .toMap()
```